# Using VBA in Excel, how can I loop through a collection of class objects to get values of object attributes?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following Macro.

```
Sub createFormFields()
    ' Declare Variables
    Dim thisFile As String
    Dim thisFileDirectory As String
    Dim thisFilePath As String
    Dim formFieldsFile As String
    Dim formFieldsFilePath As String
    Dim customer As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim fileVersion As String
    Dim fileExtension As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim currentAsTime As String
    Dim formFieldsWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim formFieldsSheet As Object
    Dim page As String
    Dim questionText As String
    Dim questionType As String
    Dim questionId As String
    Dim topic1 As String
    Dim topic2 As String
    Dim notes As String
    Dim dateAdded As String
    Dim questions As Collection
    Dim oQuestion As New cQuestion

    ' Activate First Question from YAML_Script_Creator file
    Range("A27").Activate

    ' Set questions collection as a new collection
    Set questions = New Collection

    ' Begin to Populate oQuestion Objects
    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            ' Ensure that variables do not carry over from previous question
            page = ""
            questionText = ""
            questionType = ""
            questionId = ""
            topic1 = ""
            topic2 = ""
            notes = ""
            dateAdded = ""
            ' Begin setting variables
            DoEvents
                ' Check if page cell is empty
                If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24)) Then
                    page = ""
                Else
                    page = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
                End If
                ' Set variables
                questionText = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                questionType = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
                questionId = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                topic1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
                topic2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
                notes = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value
                dateAdded = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value

                ' Set values to oQuestion Object from variables
                oQuestion.page = page
                oQuestion.questionText = questionText
                oQuestion.questionType = questionType
                oQuestion.questionId = questionId
                oQuestion.topic1 = topic1
                oQuestion.topic2 = topic2
                oQuestion.notes = notes
                oQuestion.dateAdded = dateAdded

                ' Add oQuestion Object to questions Collection
                questions.Add oQuestion

                ' Move down to the next question
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        End If
    Loop


    ' Save Pertenate Data for new Form Fields File from YAML_Script_Creator file
    customer = Range("B3").Value
    newFileName = Range("F18").Value
    fileVersion = Range("F19").Value
    fileExtension = Range("F20").Value
    filePath = Range("F21").Value
    formFieldsFile = customer & newFileName & fileVersion & fileExtension
    formFieldsFilePath = filePath & formFieldsFile
    Debug.Print formFieldsFilePath

    ' If file already exists, delete it
    If Dir(formFieldsFilePath) <> "" Then
        Kill (formFieldsFilePath)
    End If

    ' Create new form fields file
    Set formFieldsWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Set Active Sheet
    Set formFieldsSheet = formFieldsWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Get current time and format it
    currentAsTime = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    ' Format new sheet
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1") = "Customer:"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B1") = customer
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1") = "Current as of:"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E1") = currentAsTime

    formFieldsSheet.Range("A3") = "Page"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B3") = "Question Text"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("C3") = "Question Type"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D3") = "Question ID"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E3") = "Topic 1"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("F3") = "Topic 2"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("G3") = "Notes on Question"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("H3") = "Date Added"

    ' Make Font Bold
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("C3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("F3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("G3").Font.Bold = True
    formFieldsSheet.Range("H3").Font.Bold = True

    ' Make Bottom Border Thick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("C3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("F3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("G3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("H3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick

    ' Set Cell Alignments
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    ' Set Column Widths
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 15.83
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 36.67
    formFieldsSheet.Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 24.17
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 25
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 20
    formFieldsSheet.Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 20
    formFieldsSheet.Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 49.17
    formFieldsSheet.Range("H1").ColumnWidth = 15.83

    ' Activate cell to being writing data to
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A4").Activate

    ' Loop through objects in questions collection
    Dim ques As cQuestion
    Debug.Print questions.Count
    For Each ques In questions
        ' Populate Form Fields
        ActiveCell = ques.page
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ques.questionText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = ques.questionType
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = ques.questionId
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = ques.topic1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = ques.topic2
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = ques.notes
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = ques.dateAdded
        ' Activate next row for next question
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next ques

    ' Save and close the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=formFieldsFilePath
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The Macro goes through rows in one Excel sheet, save the data from each column in that row to an object which I have written a class for, add each object to a collection, and then write the data to a new Excel sheet in a new workbook.

However, the problem I am running into is while looping through the collection by each object I keep reading out the same data. The collection has 34 items inside of it, each one being different. When looping through the collection, it appears that it is only reading the last object repeatedly. I know each object is different as I have debugged it and printed out the count of the collection.

Example of data I am reading in:

```
TextQuestion    ques_1234566543 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   0   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    1   Income  1       11/29/17    Page1   This is the first question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566544 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   1   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    2   Income  2       11/30/17            This is the secondquestion
TextQuestion    ques_1234566545 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   2   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    3   Income  3       12/1/17             This is the third question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566546 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   3   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    4   Income  4       12/2/17             This is the fourth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566547 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   4   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    5   Income  5       12/3/17             This is the fifth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566548 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   5   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    6   Income  6       12/4/17             This is the sixth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566549 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   6   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    7   Income  7       12/5/17             This is the seventh question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566550 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   7   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    8   Income  8       12/6/17             This is the eighth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566551 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   8   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    9   Income  9       12/7/17             This is the nineth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566552 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   9   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    10  Income  10      12/8/17     Page2   This is the tenth question
TextQuestion    ques_1234566553 Name    null    TargetAndBaseline   10  true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    0.5 0.2 Identity    11  Income  11      12/9/17             This is the eleventh question
```

Example of the out put:

```
Customer:   ParkerInc       Current as of:  11/30/17 11:24          

Page    Question Text   Question Type   Question ID     Topic 1    Topic 2  Notes on Question            Date Added
        Name            TextQuestion    ques_1234566576 Identity   Income   This is the first question   1/1/18
        Name            TextQuestion    ques_1234566576 Identity   Income   This is the second question  1/1/18
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not collect the information in an array?  Are you doing anything with the info other than transferring it to another sheet?

Comment: Not doing any mods on the data, however, from what I read online, and in VBA, an array is more difficult to work with when the number of items you are adding to it is not set. Is this not true and can an array in VBA be dynamic in that I can continue to add to it without care for the eventual size?

Comment: Half true.  You can resize arrays dynamically with `ReDim Preserve`, and if there is some way to get a count of the items you'll be loading (total number of rows?  Only those rows with the Page field populated?) then you can do a quick count and dimension the array to the appropriate size right off the bat.  Either way, using an array is going to be a much easier solution than a collection of custom objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that getting the same information for every Object in the Collection is that there is only one Object in the Collection with multiple references to it.  When you store an Object in a Collection or an Array you are not actually storing the Object just a reference to the memory location of the object's instance.

What you need to do is instantiate a new Object during each iteration and then add the reference to the new Object to the Collection.

```
Do
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Set questions = New Collection
```

Comment: So adding the single line of code under the Else statement should do the trick?

Comment: Yes.  You also don't need to use the auto-instancing variable `New` when using `Set`.

Comment: This ended up working with a little modification: Set questions = New Collection
    ' Begin to Populate oQuestion Objects
    Do
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Set oQuestion = New cQuestion

Answer (score 0):

Refactored code using arrays:

```
Sub createFormFields()

    'Declare Variables
    Dim Questions() As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim QuestionIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim customer As String, newFileName As String, fileVersion As String
    Dim fileExtension As String, filePath As String, formFieldsFile As String
    Dim formFieldsFilepath As String, currentAsTime As String
    Dim formFieldsWorkbook As Workbook, formFieldsSheet As Worksheet

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim Questions(1 To LastRow - 26, 1 To 7)
        For i = 27 To LastRow
            QuestionIndex = QuestionIndex + 1
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 1) = .Cells(i, "C").Value  'Question Text
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 2) = .Cells(i, "A").Value  'Question Type
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 3) = .Cells(i, "B").Value  'Question ID
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 4) = .Cells(i, "S").Value  'Topic 1
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 5) = .Cells(i, "U").Value  'Topic 2
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 6) = .Cells(i, "Z").Value  'Notes
            Questions(QuestionIndex, 7) = .Cells(i, "X").Value  'Date Added
        Next i
    End With

    ' Save Pertenate Data for new Form Fields File from YAML_Script_Creator file
    customer = Range("B3").Value
    newFileName = Range("F18").Value
    fileVersion = Range("F19").Value
    fileExtension = Range("F20").Value
    If Left(fileExtension, 1) <> "." Then fileExtension = "." & fileExtension
    filePath = Range("F21").Value
    If Right(filePath, 1) <> "\" Then filePath = filePath & "\"
    formFieldsFile = customer & newFileName & fileVersion & fileExtension
    formFieldsFilepath = filePath & formFieldsFile
    Debug.Print formFieldsFilepath

    ' If file already exists, delete it
    If Dir(formFieldsFilepath) <> "" Then
        Kill (formFieldsFilepath)
    End If

    ' Create new form fields file
    Set formFieldsWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    ' Set Active Sheet
    Set formFieldsSheet = formFieldsWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Get current time and format it
    currentAsTime = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

    ' Format new sheet
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1") = "Customer:"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B1") = customer
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1") = "Current as of:"
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E1") = currentAsTime

    formFieldsSheet.Range("A3:H3") = Array("Page", "Question Text", "Question Type", "Question ID", "Topic 1", "Topic 2", "Notes on Question", "Date Added")

    ' Make Font Bold
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1,D1,A3:H3").Font.Bold = True

    ' Make Bottom Border Thick
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A3:H3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick

    ' Set Cell Alignments
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    ' Set Column Widths
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 15.83
    formFieldsSheet.Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 36.67
    formFieldsSheet.Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 24.17
    formFieldsSheet.Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 25
    formFieldsSheet.Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 20
    formFieldsSheet.Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 20
    formFieldsSheet.Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 49.17
    formFieldsSheet.Range("H1").ColumnWidth = 15.83

    ' Activate cell to being writing data to
    formFieldsSheet.Range("A4").Resize(UBound(Questions, 1), UBound(Questions, 2)).Value = Questions

    formFieldsWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=formFieldsFilepath
    formFieldsWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```